# Submit button action

Tags: forms, button, onclick, submit, action

```
<FORM ID='htmlform' action="" onsubmit="return valforms(this)">
.....
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Submit">
```

When the user is done filling out the form, and clicks the submit button, I want all of the form information to be sent to me.  How do I do this?  This is only part of the code, the whole code is too long for me to type in here.

Comment: You'll need a server side language to do something with the data (save it in a file, database, email it or simply process it).

Which one will you use?

Comment: @PoeHaH well I'm thinking to use it with email.  I really don't know about anything except html coding, and I cheat with Javascript sometimes, besides that, I'm at a blank for all other programming language.

Comment: @PoeHaH I also looked up on google and see this .asp thing. What is that? everytime I check it out, I get confused by the programming language.

Comment: asp is a server side scripting technology from Microsoft. Though, if you're a beginner, I'd sugest PHP. It's really easy and you can just write it in between your HTML code. It's free to download and with just one program, you can test it on your own computer

Comment: @PoeHaH the problem with PHP, is that our computers, don't really like it.  I'm pretty much the most fluent in computer coding right now, and the youngest one also, not that I'm showing off, but no one else can really do this.

Comment: Well for what you want to do, you need a bit more knowledge anyway, so I'm just telling you which language I would choose to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reply on your question:

> Oh, so like the page that emails the data is that an html page that I can have a message saying, "Thank you for your interest, you will hear back from us soon." and then have the page redirect to the home page again? I hope I'm not getting too complicated with this

You're almost right. Let me explain it to you:

- the user gets a HTML page that was made in PHP, ASP,.. to fill in
  some data in a form
- the user fills in the data and clicks a button
- The action on the button tells the server to process the page, or have another page to process it. Let's call this page PageX
- PageX (written in PHP, ASP,...) will email the data to you
- You can also have pageX return some text to the user's browser saying "thank you for your interest,....". You can also make a redirect to another page from this page

Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes it does. Now what would the PHP page code look like? I have seen examples with things like- 
    $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
    $Lname = $_POST["Lname"]; 
and such, but what would an example look like?

Comment: I hope I'm not making this too complicated. I'm giving myself a headache.

Comment: examples enough on the web :) for example this: http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/feedbackphp.shtml

Since I'm doing a lot here for you, consider upvoting some answers ^^

Comment: How do you get reputation? It says I need 15 reputation to up vote.

Comment: by answering questions and such. But it's okay, I'm doing this to help you; not to gain points :)

Answer (score 0):

The `action` part of the form element tells the browser what URL to post the information to. You would need to specify some page with some server-side code that would take that information and store it or send it in an email. The `onsubmit` part of your form element fires a JavaScript event that can be handled on the client's machine. You cannot do much on the client's machine without sending the data back to the server.

Comment: so to have the form information sent to my company's email that will handle applications, I need to type what for the action?  Like action="sendemailtoheitfieldmichael@yahoo.com"

Comment: No, you need to type: action = "somepage.someExtention". That page will be on the server, which can email the data. Your standard browser (client) can't send emails

Comment: @PoeHaH Oh, so like the page that emails the data is that an html page that I can have a message saying, "Thank you for your interest, you will hear back from us soon." and then have the page redirect to the home page again? I hope I'm not getting too complicated with this.

Comment: I'll explain it in an answer because the formatting on this commenting thing is terrible..

Comment: @PoeHah, ok thank you. And I think I'll post the whole code too

Comment: @PoeHaH, I can't post the whole code, it's 5,000ish too long. ha